# Slides on React Swiper carousel are overlapping on smaller viewports, how to fix this?

Tags: css, reactjs, carousel, swiper.js

On bigger viewports, it looks like this:

[image]

But on smaller viewports, the slides overlap

[image]

Now the obvious solution to this is to simply set the number of `slidesToShow` to a lesser amount on smaller viewports. However this would be way too much of a hassle to set a viewport for every single slide number. Anybody know how to fix this whilst maintaining being able to scroll from slide to slide in a consistent manner? the code:

```
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

import './App.css';
import 'swiper/swiper.scss';
import 'swiper/components/navigation/navigation.scss';
import 'swiper/components/pagination/pagination.scss';
import 'swiper/components/scrollbar/scrollbar.scss';

SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]);

const Slide = ({data}) => {
    const styles = {
        width: '200px',
        height: '200px',
        margin: 'auto',
        background: 'lightblue',
        border: '1px solid black'}
    return (
        <div style={styles}>
            {data}
        </div>
    )
}

function App() {
    const settings = {
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    };
    const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
        <p>asdf</p>
          <Swiper
              spaceBetween={10}
              slidesPerView={3}
              navigation
              pagination={{ clickable: true }}
              scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}
              onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
              onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
          >
              {
                  numbers.map(
                      (item) => {
                          return (
                              <SwiperSlide><Slide data={item}/></SwiperSlide>
                              )
                      })
              }
          </Swiper>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I want to know too